# Tokens in civicrm webform - not showing contact

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, tokens

Webform has a browser for 'available tokens'. civicrm-contact appears in it, but none of the tokens seem to work. Is there anything I have to do to enable them ?

If I put this in the confirmation message of a testform

```
current-user:civicrm-contact:display-name
[current-user:civicrm-contact:display-name]
current-user:name
[current-user:name]
submission:user:civicrm-contact:display-name
[submission:user:civicrm-contact:display-name]
submission:user:name
[submission:user:name]
current-user:civicrm-contact:id
[current-user:civicrm-contact:id]
```

The result, when filled out by a valid civi contact, is

```
current-user:civicrm-contact:display-name
current-user:name
pike
submission:user:civicrm-contact:display-name
submission:user:name
pike
current-user:civicrm-contact:id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect those tokens are coming from another module (possibly CiviCRM itself). I never added any token support to webform_civicrm. That said, the best way to achieve your goal is probably to use the token from the contact_1:existing_contact field. This has the upshot of working correctly even when the user is anonymous. It's something like

```
[submission:values:civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_existing]
```

(but would need to be adjusted if it is inside a fieldset)

Comment: Is there a way to get to, for example, the display name like that ? Or should I include the fields I need and I use a 'hidden' element for them (alas, display_name is not a field .. )

Comment: that token will render the display name of the contact